# Setting up wiretap for logging in Spring Integration (with DSL)

Tags: spring-integration

I'm trying to set up a simple wiretap for logging in Spring. Towards this end I have

```
.wireTap("loggingFlow.input")
```

in my flow and then

```
@Bean 
public IntegrationFlow loggingFlow() {
    return f -> f.log();
}
```

following what I found at http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html

which gives me a MessageDeliveryException with 
    Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application:local.loggingFlow.channel#1'.

I did notice while writing this that the above link has the .wireTap() on a MessageChannels.queue() rather than on a flow & I wonder if that's why this doesn't work. Any suggestions on how to most concisely enable logging with wiretaps in my flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.log()` itself is a wiretap. It currently can't be the last element in a flow. Fixed in 5.0. Workaround is to add `.channel("nullChannel")` after a final `.log()`.

Or just use `.log` instead of `.wiretap`.